# sticky navigation bar dysfunctional

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm relatively new to web development and I have been assigned a practise "job" from one of my family members. I'm having trouble with the "sticky" function. It's a navbar with a dropdown. When I try to scroll down to test the sticky function, it won't work.

Here is my code sample:

```css
.nav {
  position: sticky;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 3990px;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav" id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="First_Page.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown" id="navbar">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="navbar">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

it's a "prototype" so please don't judge it too harshly.

have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `top` or `bottom` property if you want to use sticky. I suggest you use `position: fixed` instead.

```css
body { /* just to see scroll */
  min-height: 200vh;
  background: linear-gradient(black, white);
}

.nav {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0.5rem; /* half the font size */
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: #333;
  display: inline-block;
  min-width: 3990px;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a,
.dropbtn {
  display: inline-block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover,
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: red;
}

li.dropdown {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="nav" id="navbar">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="First_Page.html">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="dropdown" id="navbar">
        <a href="#" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a>
        <div class="dropdown-content" id="navbar">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```